# using multiple css grids - using two grids but wanting them both to start at top of page

Tags: javascript, css

why wont JS let me change the display property of these two CSS grids? I have the JS (overlay) in a file that is accessed asynchronously in the html header element.

I keep getting message "*Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementByClassName is not a function
at changegrid (overlayfade.js:37)*"

HTML below:

```
 <body>

      <section class="myContainer">
        <section id="overlay"><a  id="storelink" target="_parent" href="store/index.html" ></a>
        </section>
        <div id="text">
          <p id="logointro">Goetia</p>
          <p id="storephrase">Genderess Printed Shirts</p>
          <p id="enterstore">Click to Enter</p>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section class="myShopContainer">
    
    <section>  
     
  </body>
```

**CSS below:**

```
.myContainer{
        
        list-style:none;
        background-color:white;
        display:grid;
        grid-template-columns:8vw 8vw 8vw 8vw 8vw 8vw 8vw 8vw 8vw 8vw 8vw 8vw;
        grid-template-rows:   9.5vh 9.5vh 9.5vh 9.5vh 9.5vh 9.5vh 9.5vh 9.5vh 9.5vh 7vh;
        grid-gap:5px;
        overflow:hidden;
      }
      .myShopContainer{
        
        list-style:none;
        background-color:white;
        display:grid;
        grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto;
        grid-template-rows:   9.5vh 9.5vh 9.5vh 9.5vh 9.5vh 9.5vh 9.5vh 9.5vh 9.5vh 7vh;
        grid-gap:5px;
        overflow:hidden;
        z-index:1;
        visbility:hidden;
        
      }
```

JS below:

document.getElementByClassName("myShopContainer").style.display = "none";

```
  function fadeOutEffect() {
 
  
    var fadeTarget1 = document.getElementById("text");
    var fadeTarget = document.getElementById("overlay");
    var fadeEffect = setInterval(function () {
              if (!fadeTarget.style.opacity)
              {
                  fadeTarget.style.opacity = 1;
                  fadeTarget1.style.opacity1 = 1;
              }
              if (fadeTarget.style.opacity > 0)
              {
                  fadeTarget.style.opacity -= 0.1;
                  fadeTarget1.style.opacity -= 0.14;
                  
              }
              else
              {
                  fadeTarget.style.zIndex="0";
                  fadeTarget1.style.zIndex="0";
                  changegrid();
                 
                  clearInterval(fadeEffect);
                  
                  
                  
              }
    }, 200);
  }
    
  document.getElementById("overlay").addEventListener('click', fadeOutEffect);
  document.getElementById("text").addEventListener('click', fadeOutEffect);
   
  function changegrid(){ 
              
              return document.getElementByClassName("myContainer").style.display = "none",document.getElementByClassName("myShopContainer").style.display = "grid";
                   
  }
```

Comment: instead of having it in `head` section did you try to add your `<script src="..."></script>` to the `body` section, right before the closing `</body>` ?

Comment: Ive realised I need to use document.getElementById("grid1").style.display = "none"

for some reason document.getElementByClassName("grid1".style.display = "none" wasn't recognised by JS...in my external JS file...any idea why? 

But yeah I now have got it working so I can use two CSS grid on same page making one disapear and the other appear..brilliant stuff...

Answer (score 0):

This works...bu why isn't document.getElementByClassName("grid1".style.display = "none"  working from an external Js file I created.

...why does it produce this error: "Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementByClassName is not a function at changegrid (overlayfade.js:37)"

```
      document.getElementById("grid2").style.display = "none";

      function fadeOutEffect() {
     
      
        var fadeTarget1 = document.getElementById("text");
        var fadeTarget = document.getElementById("overlay");
        var fadeEffect = setInterval(function () {
                  if (!fadeTarget.style.opacity)
                  {
                      fadeTarget.style.opacity = 1;
                      fadeTarget1.style.opacity1 = 1;
                  }
                  if (fadeTarget.style.opacity > 0)
                  {
                      fadeTarget.style.opacity -= 0.1;
                      fadeTarget1.style.opacity -= 0.14;
                      
                  }
                  else
                  {
                      fadeTarget.style.zIndex="0";
                      fadeTarget1.style.zIndex="0";
                      changegrid();
                     
                      clearInterval(fadeEffect);
                      
                      
                      
                  }
        }, 200);
      }
        
      document.getElementById("overlay").addEventListener('click', fadeOutEffect);
      document.getElementById("text").addEventListener('click', fadeOutEffect);
       
      function changegrid(){
                  
                  return document.getElementById("grid1").style.display = "none",
                  document.getElementById("grid2").style.display = "grid";
                       
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out document.getElementByClassName("etc") is not supported by all browsers...but I'm using a 2018 chromebook...so I'm confused about it all...

Either way I'm happy I figured it out - now everyone know how to use two separate CSS grids on the same page...lol....

grid A is for animation, grid B for content... switch between grids...

Everyone please forgive me...